# Office.js | excel add-in | print excel data rendering stats for performance analysis

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, office365api

I am using office.js, react, javascript to create excel add-ins. I wants to print stats like time taken to render 1000 rows of data, 10,000 rows of data, 50,000 and 100,000 rows of data.
Below code using to render data on excel using range.

```
const startDate = new Date();
Excel.run(context => {
        const app = context.workbook.application;
        const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('sheet1');
        return context.sync().then(() => {
            app.suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync();
            const range = sheet.getRange(`A1:Z2000`); // range to print data on sheet
            range.values = outputData; // outputData is nothing but array of 1000, 10K, 100K rows with approx 80/100/200 columns
            range.format.autofitColumns();
            console.log(
                'time taken to render data',
                (new Date().getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000,
            );
            return context.sync();
        });
    })
```

On WEB excel I could see below exceRich API taking around 5.60 seconds. PFA SS.
https://excel.officeapps.live.com/x/_vti_bin/EwaInternalWebService.json/ExecuteRichApiRequest?waccluster=PUS1
[image]

**Is there any way to print how much time taken to render this data on WEB excel and desktop excel?
Also How we can optimize this rendering time.**
Already tried with slicing response object with small small groups but its taking more time than above pasted code.
Please suggest as we need to present this stats on priority. Thanks in advance.